# log rotation improper

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have a log rotation script for audit.log as below, where I found as per the script, instead of rotating of log for every 512MB, it is rotating every 1 hour exactly, however, the 8 log files are maintained. I have checked the logrotate.conf and other parameters and I don't see mentioned anywhere the log rotation time interval-  1 hour time interval. How to debug this case?

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/audit

#
#
/var/log/audit.log {
        weekly
        rotate 8
        size 512M
        compress
        missingok
        copytruncate
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s.log
}
```

Comment: Running `logrotate --debug` as root will leave the log files untouched but give your debug information in case there's something wrong. Can you try that?